# jQuery lags during slideDown/Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lag

in the beginning I would to say that I've read bunch of tutorials and articles about it and nothing solves my problem. Responsive menu is lagging during the sliding down or up. It's the first time when it happens, all the time everything worked smooth and fine.

here the jQuery Code:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 820) {
    $('nav ul').addClass('mobile');
} else {
    $('nav ul').removeClass('mobile');
}
var hiddenContent = $( ".mobile" );
$( ".responsive" ).click(
    function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (hiddenContent.is( ":visible" )){
            hiddenContent.slideUp('fast');

        } else {
            hiddenContent.slideDown('fast');
        }
    }
);
```

I believe that jQuery is all right. 
The link to the wbsite http://kemizo.pl/en/index
I've tried different jQuery scripts and fixed width to ul and li elements. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I do not experience any lagging on the provided website.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, check the responsive menu when your viewport is smaller than 820px. are you using a jQuery plugin to create this responsive menu?

Comment: Yes, I know obviously I'm checking the responsive menu on smaller viewport.  It's not a plugin. Just a simple script. But so far I ve been using it without any problems. It's the first time when it's lagging.

Comment: @user3660586, I think your `$( ".mobile" )` returns quite a lot of elements all sitting within your `nav` buried in a number of `li` elements & hence, jQuery tries to animate *all* of them. This could be the reason of the slowdown.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will use a plug in in the future. For now I will skip animations! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your style `nav * { transition:all 0.3s; }` in line `238` of `styles.css` interferes with jQuery's `slideDown()` (or whatever animation method) you are using. Disable it temporarily to see if the animation runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS3 animation, or existing menu jQuery plugins

Comment: This doesn't really qualify as an answer :/

Comment: he cannot leave comment with his present reputation, so i hope you Got the point.